# How to calculate new position of a rectangle after translation and rotation?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, rectangles

I have a rectangle - lets say 100 long by 75 high. Origin been bottom left corner.  I move the rectangle up and across by 10 and rotate by 3 degrees from centre of part.  How do I calculate the new position of the origin in X and Y.

I need to make only 3 measurements: 2 from X direction, and 1 from Y.
I will use a laser to get 3 master measurements. I will move part and re-measure from same positions.
I can compare new measurements to original but do not know to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for the coordinates $(x,y)$ of the lower left corner of a rectangle of dimensions $(w,h)$ after a translation $(t_x,t_y)$ and rotation $\theta$

[image: fig1]

The answer is

$$ \begin{aligned}
 x & = \tfrac{w}{2} + t_x - \tfrac{w}{2} \cos \theta + \tfrac{h}{2} \sin \theta \\
 y & = \tfrac{h}{2} + y_y - \tfrac{w}{2} \sin \theta - \tfrac{h}{2} \cos \theta 
\end{aligned}$$

The answer comes from trigonometry where you trace each coordinate from the origin to the center, add the translation and rotation, and then back to the corner.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you make the origin be the center of the rectangle.  Then a point that starts at $(a,b)$ will move by the translation to $(a-10,b+10)$  A rotation of $3^\circ$ will move that to $((a-10)\cos 3^\circ-(b+10) \sin 3^\circ,(a-10)\sin 3^\circ + (b+10) \cos 3^\circ)$

It is not clear what you are asking in the second part.  It seems disconnected from the first.

Answer (score 0):

If you know linear algebra you could put the transformation functions into matrices and the computer would calculate what would happen to the coordinates.